# Checking if passed string is an integer

Tags: c, string, integer

I am making an app that records the time, userID, and weight. How can I check if the first token passed is an integer? I thought I would use isdigit, but that just works for single chars. I want to output Invalid time if the first token is not an integer. I'm currently using

```
sscanf(userInput, "%d %s %f", &timestamp, userID, &weight);
```

If the first token is not an integer (has alphabets for example) I still get a number for the variable timestamp,, which I don't want.

```
int main()
{
   char userInput[99];
   int timestamp, timestampT = 0;
   char userID[31];
   userID[0] = 0;
   float weight, weightT, day, rateW;

   while(fgets(userInput, 99, stdin) != NULL){
       sscanf(userInput, "%d %s %f", &timestamp, userID, &weight);

       if(timestamp == 0 ){
           printf("%s\n", "Invalid time");
       }
       else if(!isalpha(userID[0]) || userID[0]=='_' || userID[0] == 0){
           printf("%s\n", "Illegal userID");
       }
       else if(weight < 30.0 || weight > 300.0){
           printf("%s\n", "Illegal weight");
       }
       else if(timestampT > 0){
           day = timestampT/86400;
           rateW = (weightT -weight)/(day - timestamp/86400);
           if(rateW > 10.0 || rateW < -10.0){
               printf("%s\n", "Suspiciously large weight change");
           }

       }
       else{
           printf("%d %s %f \n", timestamp, userID, weight);
           timestampT = timestamp;
           timestamp = 0;
           weightT = weight;
       }

       userID[0] = 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: build another string using the results of the sscanf, then compare the original to the rebuild string. if they're different, then something didn't convert correctly. e.g. `foo = printf('%d %s, %f', the, values, here); if (!strcmp(foo, userinput)) { ruh_roh(); }`

Comment: Start by using the result of [`sscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to determine how many parameters were *successfully* parsed. [Heed the **Sixth Commandment**](http://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html)

Comment: You can check all characters of a string with `isdigit` for your timestamp or with `isalpha` for your ID. (Better write functions for that.) Or you could read the time in as string in your first `sscanf` and then run `sscanf(`..., "%d", ...)` on that string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy way:

```
char dummy;
sscanf( userInput, "%d%c %s %f", &timestamp, &dummy, userId, &weight );
if ( !isspace( dummy ))
   // invalid timestamp input, handle as appropriate
```

The `%d` conversion specifier tells `sscanf` to leave the first non-digit character in the input stream, which will be picked up by the `%c` conversion specifier.  If this character is anything other than whitespace, then the input was not a valid integer string.

Less easy, but IMO the more robust way:

First, read your timestamp as text:

```
char timestampStr[N+1]; // where N is the number of digits in the time stamp
...
sscanf(userInput, "%s %s %f", timestampStr, userID, &weight);
```

Then use the `strtol` library function to convert the text to an integer value:

```
char *chk;
int tmp = (int) strtol( timestampStr, &chk, 10 );
```

After the conversion, `chk` will point to the first non-digit character in `timestampStr`; if this character is anything other than whitespace or the 0 terminator, then the input string was *not* a valid integer:

```
if ( *chk == 0 || isspace( *chk ))
{
  timestamp = tmp;
}
else
{
  // invalid timestamp input, handle as appropriate
}
```

I prefer this method because it won't assign anything to `timestamp` if the input is invalid; this may or may not matter for your purposes.

**EDIT**

As chux points out, you should also check the return value of `sscanf` (I rarely use the `*scanf` functions for interactive input, so I never think about that).  In the first case, if the result is < 4, then you have a problem regardless of the timestamp and should throw the whole line away.  Similarly, in the second case, if the result is < 3, you didn't get the input you wanted and you should throw the whole line away.

In practice, what I do is use `fgets` to read the line and then break it into tokens using `strtok`, and then use `strtol` or `strtod` to do any numeric conversions as necessary.